# Algebra equation help?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\begin{align}
&4\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{1}{2}x=24\\
&\frac{17}{4}x-\frac{2}{4}x=24\\
&\frac{15}{4}x=24&&\implies x=\frac{96}{14}\\
\end{align}$$

Can anyone help me as I am not sure I got the right answer.

Comment: $4(1/4)=1$, not $17/4$, unless you actually meant to write $4\frac{1}{4}$ as a mixed fraction.

Comment: Is that equation $4\frac14x-\frac12x=24$?

Comment: $4(1/4)=4\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: I edited the question using Latex, however while doing that I noticed that your last line should be $\frac{96}{15}$ and I assume one answer already points that out

Comment: Thanks Asaf, first I did not understand the question I notice you modified the latex code.

Comment: And the comments above is why people in college should *not* use mixed fractions. *Ever.*

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I'd have left out "in college" from that statement, though I suppose it'd then require a few qualifiers on the "Ever."

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that "4(1/4)" is supposed to be the mixed fraction $4\!\frac{1}{4}$, then your reasoning and answer is correct, *except* that in the penultimate line, you wrote "$24x$" when you should just have $24$ (since you didn't multiply both sides by $x$), and that in the last line, you mean $\frac{96}{15}$, not $\frac{96}{14}$ (I assume this is just a typo). Finally, although it does not affect the correctness of your answer, you should also make sure to reduce your final result to lowest terms; neither $\frac{96}{14}$ nor $\frac{96}{15}$ is in lowest terms.